# Let's Crash things

Tags: grammar

For play with a toddler and his bunch of cars, 
Do you say, "let's crash some cars" or "let's crash some cars with the monster truck" ?

Thank you.

Comment: Let me ask one more thing: if you want to crash something not by driving into something else, but by using hammar or hand, or by throwing, or even you don't want mention the methods but what you want to do: crashing,  how would the sentence go? 1. I am going to crash the toy. 2. I will crash the toy with this hammer. like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Neither is correct** for what you seem to be using it for. Instead, you could say "Let's knock over some cars", or "Let's crash *into* some cars with the monster truck."

You could also chance the sentence order to "Let's crash the monster truck into some cars."

---

The first sentence, "let's crash some cars", is grammatically correct in and of itself, but it is incorrect for the purpose you are using it for because "crash", when used without a preposition, refers to what the *driver of the vehicle* does, or to *what the vehicle itself does*. In other words, you can "crash a car" with the toddler by holding the car and "driving" it into something, but not by hitting it with something else.

Instead, you can use a different form of the verb "crash" by adding the preposition "into", as in the example sentences at the top.

The above also applies to the second sentence; also, the verb "crash" is never used with the preposition "with"; it simply isn't something that happens in the English language.

Comment: How about this sentence:  I will crash that bus by driving into it?